# Java/JDBC/Swing - Issues With Retrieving Next Record

Tags: java, mysql, swing, sqlite, jdbc

I am having some issues with retrieving the next record within my SQLite Database. I've *tried* to create a new ArrayList and instance of an Employee (a class with getters/setters) however, I still have issues. I've been searching the web for the last day and a half trying to solve this issue. I've tried using `if(rs.next)/while(rs.next)` however, only `while` seems to work. I've looked online and followed several tutorials but encounter the issue `SQLITE TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.` I have implemented :

```
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
```

But still no luck, so I decided to add an iterator/counter as ID within my SQLite Database is unique. However, the issue appears to be the iterator/counter doesn't increment, however, if I set the value manually i.e. 2, I get the second record within the database and so forth.

```
nextEmployee.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            int i = 1;
            try {                   
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);                        

                 String sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Gender, DOB, Address, Postcode, NIN, JobTitle, StartDate, Salary, Email from employees WHERE ID= " +(i);                                     

                pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();    

                for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
                    while (rs.next()){

                        String  id = rs.getString(1);
                        String  name = rs.getString(2);
                        String  gender = rs.getString(3);
                        String  dob = rs.getString(4);
                        String  Address = rs.getString(5); 
                        String  Postcode = rs.getString(6);
                        String  NIN = rs.getString(7);
                        String  JobTitle = rs.getString(8);
                        String  StartDate = rs.getString(9);
                        String  Salary = rs.getString(10);
                        String  email = rs.getString(11);

                        idTextField.setText(id);
                        nameTextField.setText(name);
                        genderTextField.setText(gender);
                        dobTextField.setText(dob);

                        addressTextField.setText(Address);
                        postcodeTextField.setText(Postcode);
                        ninTextField.setText(NIN);
                        jobtitleTextField.setText(JobTitle);
                        startdateTextField.setText(StartDate);
                        salaryTextField.setText(Salary);
                        emailTextField.setText(email);


                        //   i++;
                        connection.commit();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee has been found");
                    }
                }                   

                rs.close();
                pst.close();
                connection.close();
            }


            catch ( Exception e1 ) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records exist");

            }
        }});
```

I'm just running out of ideas. This is the last piece of the puzzle, I've successfully implemented create/insert, delete, search, update. Could someone tell me as to why this iterator/counter will not increment?

Thank you.

EDIT -

Employee Class

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    private int id;
    private float salary;
    private String startDate;
    private String title;
    private String email;



    public int getid(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public float getsalary(){
        return salary;
    }

    public void setsalary(float salary){
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getstartDate(){
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setstartDate(String startDate){
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String gettitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void settitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getemail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setemial(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }



    public Employee(){
        this("", 'N', "", new Date(), "", "", 0, 0, "", "", "");
    }

    public Employee( String Name, char Sex, String natIncsNumber, Date date, String address, String postcode, int ID, float Salary, String Startdate, String Title, String Email) {
        super(Name, Sex,natIncsNumber, date, address, postcode);
        this.id = ID;
        salary = 0.0f;
        this.startDate = Startdate;
        this.title = Title;
        this.email = Email;
    }


    public void setSalary(float salry){
        salary = salry;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Employee ID = " + id+ ", Employee Salary = " + salary + " Start Date = " + startDate + 
                " Title = " + title + " Email = " + email + super.toString();
    }


}
```

Person Class-

```
import java.io.*;
public class Person implements Serializable{

    protected String name;
    protected char gender;
    protected String natIncsNo;
    protected Date dob;
    protected String Address;
    protected String Postcode;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(char gender){
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getnatIncsNo(){
        return natIncsNo;
    }

    public void setnatIncsNo(String natIncsNo){
        this.natIncsNo = natIncsNo;
    }

    public Date getdob(){
        return dob;
    }

    public void setdob(Date dob){
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address){
        this.Address = Address;
    }

    public String getPostcode(){
        return Postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String Postcode){
        this.Postcode = Postcode;
    }


    public Person(String Name, char Sex, String natIncsNumber, Date date, String address, String postcode) {
        name = Name;
         gender = Sex;
         natIncsNo = natIncsNumber;
        dob = date;
        Address = address;
        Postcode = postcode;
    }


        public Person(){
            this("", 'N', "", new Date(), "", "");
        }

    public String toString(){



        String output = " Name: " + name + " Gender: " + gender +  " National Insurance Number: " + natIncsNo + 
                " Date Of Birth : " + dob + 
                 " Address: " + Address + " Postcode: " + Postcode;

        return output;

    }
    }
```

EDIT X 2-

EmployeeDAO Class

```
import java.security.spec.ECFieldF2m;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EmployeeDAO extends Employee {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public EmployeeDAO() { 



        Connection connection = null;
        try { 
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection - database driver found");




        //insertEmployeeAtID(); 
        //selectAllEmployees();
        //insertEmployee();
        //deleteEmployeeByID();
    }





    public Statement getConnection() {
        return st;
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException { 
        if (con != null) con.close();
    }



    public ArrayList<Employee> selectAllEmployees(){
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Read operation - database successfully opened");

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT * from employees" );
            while ( resultset.next() ) {
                int id = resultset.getInt("id");
                String  name = resultset.getString("name");
                String  email = resultset.getString("email");
                String  gender = resultset.getString("gender");
                String  dob = resultset.getString("dob");
                String  Address = resultset.getString("address"); 
                String  Postcode = resultset.getString("Postcode");
                String  NIN = resultset.getString("NIN");
                String  JobTitle = resultset.getString("JobTitle");
                String  StartDate = resultset.getString("StartDate");
                String  Salary = resultset.getString("Salary");


                System.out.println( "ID : " + id );
                System.out.println( "Name : " + name );
                System.out.println( "Gender : " + gender );
                System.out.println( "Date Of Birth : " + dob );
                System.out.println( "Address : " + Address );
                System.out.println( "Postcode : " + Postcode );
                System.out.println( "National Insurance Number : " + NIN );
                System.out.println( "Job Title : " + JobTitle );
                System.out.println( "Start Date : " + StartDate );
                System.out.println( "Salary : " + Salary );
                System.out.println( "Email: " + email );
                System.out.println();
            }
            resultset.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Read operation successfully done"); 
        return new ArrayList<Employee>();

    }


    public String selectEmployeeByName() {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Read operation - database successfully opened");

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT * from employees WHERE Name = 'Brad Stones';" );
            while ( resultset.next() ) {
                int id = resultset.getInt("id");
                String  name = resultset.getString("name");
                String  email = resultset.getString("email");
                String  gender = resultset.getString("gender");
                String  dob = resultset.getString("dob");
                String  Address = resultset.getString("address"); 
                String  Postcode = resultset.getString("Postcode");
                String  NIN = resultset.getString("NIN");
                String  JobTitle = resultset.getString("JobTitle");
                String  StartDate = resultset.getString("StartDate");
                String  Salary = resultset.getString("Salary");

                /*
                System.out.println( "ID : " + id );
                System.out.println( "Name : " + name );
                System.out.println( "Gender : " + gender );
                System.out.println( "Date Of Birth : " + dob );
                System.out.println( "Address : " + Address );
                System.out.println( "Postcode : " + Postcode );
                System.out.println( "National Insurance Number : " + NIN );
                System.out.println( "Job Title : " + JobTitle );
                System.out.println( "Start Date : " + StartDate );
                System.out.println( "Salary : " + Salary );
                System.out.println( "Email: " + email );
                System.out.println();
                */
            }
            resultset.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Read operation successfully done"); 
          return toString();
    }


    public boolean insertEmployee(){

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Insert operation -database successfully opened");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql =  "INSERT INTO employees (id, name, gender, NIN, dob, Address, Postcode,startDate, salary, email, JobTitle) "
                    + "VALUES ('1', 'Brad Stones', 'M', 'YU6593864T', '09-01-1987', '100 Dalton Road', 'M1 7TA', '09-01-1981','25000', 'BradSmith@mail.com', 'Tutor')";


            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            statement.close();
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Records successfully created");
        return false;
    }




    public boolean insertEmployeeAtID(){

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
          connection.setAutoCommit(false);
          System.out.println("Update operation - database successfully opened");

          statement = connection.createStatement();
          String sql = "UPDATE employees set JobTitle = 'Potato' where ID=1;";
          statement.executeUpdate(sql);
          connection.commit(); 
          statement.close();
          connection.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Update operation successfully done");
        return false;
      }




    public boolean deleteEmployeeByID(){

         Connection connection = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            try {
              Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
              connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
              connection.setAutoCommit(false);
              System.out.println("Delete operation -database successfully opened");
              statement = connection.createStatement();
              String sql = "DELETE from employees where ID= 1";
              statement.executeUpdate(sql);
              connection.commit();
              statement.close();
              connection.close();
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
              System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
              System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("Delete operation successfully done");
        return false;
    }

}
```

nextEmployee Method-

```
List<Employee> list= empDAO.selectAllEmployees();

        int counter=0;
        nextEmployee.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            boolean isfirstTime = true;


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isfirstTime) {
                    Connection connection = null;
                    PreparedStatement pst = null;
                    Statement statement = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    int i = 1;
                    try {

                        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
                        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

                        String sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Gender, DOB, Address, Postcode, NIN, JobTitle, StartDate, Salary, Email from employees WHERE ID= "
                                + (i);

                        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        rs = pst.executeQuery();

                        while(rs.next()){
                            EmployeeDAO empDao=new EmployeeDAO();
                            //set the variables for the employee


                            String id = rs.getString(1);
                            String name = rs.getString(2);
                            String gender = rs.getString(3);
                            String dob = rs.getString(4);
                            String Address = rs.getString(5);
                            String Postcode = rs.getString(6);
                            String NIN = rs.getString(7);
                            String JobTitle = rs.getString(8);
                            String StartDate = rs.getString(9);
                            String Salary = rs.getString(10);
                            String email = rs.getString(11);

                            idTextField.setText(id);
                            nameTextField.setText(name);
                            genderTextField.setText(gender);
                            dobTextField.setText(dob);

                            addressTextField.setText(Address);
                            postcodeTextField.setText(Postcode);
                            ninTextField.setText(NIN);
                            jobtitleTextField.setText(JobTitle);
                            startdateTextField.setText(StartDate);
                            salaryTextField.setText(Salary);
                            emailTextField.setText(email);

                            list.add(empDao);


                        }


                        rs.close();
                        pst.close();
                        connection.close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception e1) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records exist");

                    }
                }else{
                    Employee emp=list.get(counter);
                    idTextField.setText(String.valueOf(emp.getid()));
                    //and so on. always get from emp
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee has been found");


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try moving `connection.commit();` before your `for` loop .

Comment: @Berger Tried it, however, since i = 1, it only returns the first record and just refuses to increment the value of i.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)` loop ?

Comment: @Berger i = idValue within the Database, and 4 in the maximum number of records I have. So for i = 1 - display the first record, i = 2 - display the second record and so forth. And I was hoping i would increment on every button click.

Answer (score 0):

with the code you posted being too much for me, ill post you some of mine code where i created a dao class and how i use it.

dao class:

```
public class SchnitzelDBDAO {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchnitzelDBDAO.class);
private Properties dbProperties;
private String action = "";
private Vector<Gericht> mealsActionPerformedOn;

public SchnitzelDBDAO() {
    dbProperties = new Properties();
    String stage = System.getProperty("stage", "prod");
    LOG.info("Loading stage properties: {} ", stage);
    String file = stage + ".settings.txt";
    try (InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file)) {
        dbProperties.load(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Properties konnten nicht geladen werden: ", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    mealsActionPerformedOn=new Vector<Gericht>();
}

private Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(dbProperties.getProperty("server"), dbProperties);
}

public Vector<Gericht> findGericht(java.util.Date von, java.util.Date bis) throws Exception {
    Vector<Gericht> v = new Vector<Gericht>();
    java.sql.Date[] dates = testDate(von, bis);
    try (Connection connect = createConnection()) {
        LOG.info("Searching for meals");
        String query = "select * from Gericht where date BETWEEN ? and ? order by date asc";
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(query);

        statement.setDate(1, dates[0]);
        statement.setDate(2, dates[1]);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Gericht g = new Gericht();
            g.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            String str = rs.getString("classification");
            g.setClassification(Classification.valueOf(str));
            g.setDate(rs.getDate("date"));
            g.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            g.setPreisExtern(rs.getBigDecimal("preisExtern"));
            g.setPreisIntern(rs.getBigDecimal("preisIntern"));
            v.add(g);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
}
```

then call it in some class like this. first line is a member variable in that class;

```
SchnitzelDBDAO dbConnector = new SchnitzelDBDAO();
dbConnector.remove(gerichte.get(table.getSelectedRow()).getDate());
```

i hope you can somehow adapt your code to mine and get your code to work properly

Comment: Dude, dude, dude, dude, dude.......... I love you so much!!!!!!!! However, just one small issue, it keeps displaying "Employee has been found" and when you select OK, it moves onto the next Employee, how can I combat this? At first I thought a Thread, however, that is also time based. I just need it to move to the next record once the button is clicked.

Comment: ahh well then you should really structure your code in another way, so you read all employees just once and save them in a list and on button click you increase a counter and get the next employee. ill try to give you a possible solution

Comment: I tried doing so, but kept getting the error with SQLite cursor - SQLITE TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Comment: i updated my answer. please have a look at it. i hope it helps you. you can delete this :SQLITE TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Comment: I just pasted in the code, had a few errors, I think I have to parse  idTextField.setText(emp.getid()); and an Integer and then pass it in as setText isn't working. How would I go about this? Also, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `idTextField.setText(String.valueOf(emp.getid()));` try this if you want to set an integer as value

Comment: No luck, my Employee extends Person which is another class. However, I just tested to see if I could retrieve a value within ID but no luck. I appreciate your help a lot mate! I really do.

Comment: it only appears to just return the first entry, this is the issue I also had. :/

Comment: how big is your list and resultset?

Comment: I have added both Employee/Person class and my list currently is 4, max I could see it ever being is 20 and thats being generous.

Comment: how many entries are in your database? the problem with the id is not because of parsing but something else

Comment: I also have an EmployeeDAO class, but I just thought that would be useful for the System.out.Println(), I may be wrong though.

Comment: Currently 4, Records consist of the following ID's 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: yes, please post the dao class too. could you explain this too me: max I could see it ever being is 20 and thats being generous?

Comment: why not use the dao class to get the result sets?

Comment: Sure, max I could see it ever being is 20 and thats being generous meaning - Currently I have 4 records, the maximum number of records that I think will possibly ever be entered is 20 as 400 other student have the same system as me. So they wish to test each function (CRUD) and test the stability of the program. That is all. And the being generous part means I think even 20 is too high, it may jut even be 10. Also added the EmployeeDAO class. :)

Comment: I thought this too, however, I'm not sure how to use the EmployeeDAO class to get the results. Could you possibly help me?

Comment: Just added it, it still only returns the first record. However, within the console it displays ALL the records. As I use System.out.printl in the .selectAllEmployees method in my EmployeeDAO class

Comment: how many more classes does the project got? i wanna try it on my pc

Comment: could you possibly show where I have to add the EmployeeDAO class and the List?

Comment: I have 8 .java classes.

Comment: in every class where you want to process the data

Comment: I have added what I think is correct? If you look at my nextEmployee method in my original post. Think I've done it wrong though.

Comment: yes you did xD. ill give you the method in a moment

Comment: updated my answer, but you will have to change pretty much in your dao class because currently it will give you a new (empty) list. also some of your sql statement could throw an error, because you insert a `;` at the end of the statement and after the string. remove the one at the end of the statement

Comment: for today this is the last help i can give you. more help comes tomorrow

Comment: Just tried it, no luck still. The console prints out all records, if I select the button again the system crashes and states database connection closed. The textfields are empty.

Comment: I appreciate it buddy! Ireally do!

Comment: in your dao don't close your connection until the program ends. and consider what you return in your methods. for max help, post all your classes, so i can maybe tomorrow fix the mistakes

Comment: can you give a short overview over your classes and what they do?

Comment: i posted you some code from me. sadly you code is way too much to completely fix all errors which could appear

Comment: I appreciate your help buddy, I really do! :)